# Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters. laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I've got problem with my laravel 5.4 I can't save the data

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'permission_id' => 'required|unique',
        'name' => 'required',
        'label' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

**Error**

> Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `unique` rule need at least the name of ur database table.

ur `rules` function should be like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'permission_id' => 'required|unique:db_table_name',
        'name' => 'required',
        'label' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

for more informations check laravel doc [unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique)